# Get rid of whitespace between Image and text in a vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I've an `ImageView` and 2  `TextViews` in a vertical `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/players"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:maxLines="15"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subs" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting too much whitespace between the image and the text underneath it. The image is being resized in to the `ImageView`. I've changed background colours: And the image looks fine: taking up the expected space for the image and no more. From other questions, I've tried `android:adjustViewBounds` attribute for the `ImageView` but this hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Show screenshot please.

Comment: Remove **`android:layout_marginTop="88dp"`** in textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing white space is following attribute in `players` TextView:

`android:layout_marginTop="88dp"`

Either remove it or reduce the space as per your need.